# fancyimpute installed, but I can't import it on Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, module, installation, python-module, fancyimpute

I spent the last 4 hours trying to install the fancyimpute module on my windows machine (on my mac I didn't have any issues) unsuccessfully. Finally, I was able to install it by manually installing the whl files for the required dependencies, but Jupyter notebook doesn't recognize the module.

[image: cmd fancyimpute install success screenshot]

[image: Jupyter error screenshot]

I really need your help, I'm getting crazy here trying to fix that...

Comment: If you search around stackoverflow more for the error you are seeing, specifically `ModuleNotFoundError` and add in the keyword 'Jupyter' fro good measure, you'll get lots of advice of how to situate your environment. I am going to suggest you simply run `%pip install fancyimpute` in your Jupyter notebook cell and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60318796/8508004).