# No module named 'gensim' but already installed it

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, gensim, word-embedding

i'm having this error problem, i have ran this script in jupyter notebook in base (root) environment, the log said that gensim library has been installed and i have run the command **!pip install gensim** before i import it, but it still can not be imported, and the error said **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'**

```
!pip install gensim
import gensim
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load('model_fasttext2.vec')
model.vector_size
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Requirement already satisfied: gensim in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.18.1 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gensim) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.0 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gensim) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: smart-open>=1.8.1 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gensim) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.3 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gensim) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: boto>=2.32 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (2.49.0)
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (1.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: bz2file in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (0.98)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from boto3->smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.16.0,>=1.15.3 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from boto3->smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (1.15.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from boto3->smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (0.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from botocore<1.16.0,>=1.15.3->boto3->smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils<0.16,>=0.10 in c:\users\ip-03\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from botocore<1.16.0,>=1.15.3->boto3->smart-open>=1.8.1->gensim) (0.15.2)
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ee4a48d372cd> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install gensim')
----> 2 import gensim
      3 from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
      4 model = KeyedVectors.load('model_fasttext2.vec')
      5 model.vector_size

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
```

Is there anyone who can help this problem? i will really appreciate your help, it will help my thesis work, thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your jupyter lab maybe running the base kernel and not the kernel of the virtual environment.

Check by doing the following:

```py
import sys
sys.executable
```

into my notebook and got the result

```
'/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

If you get the above instead of the below then that means you're using the wrong kernel.

```
'/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python'
```

You can solve it by creating a new iPython kernel for your new environment. Read more [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments).

````sh
conda install -n myenv ipython
conda activate myenv
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```Then, to run Jupyter Lab in the new environment:
````

Comment: You can also [this](https://interviewbubble.com/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-gensim/)

Comment: Along the line of what @Azy-Crw4282, is suggesting, inside your notebook you an now use the `%pip` magic, see [here](https://hub.packtpub.com/ipython-7-3-releases-with-conda-and-pip-magics-and-python-3-8-compatibility/) to install into the environment that the current kernel is using. Inside your notebook, run `%pip install gensim`.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't catch typo before time to edit expired. That should read '...inside your notebook you can now use the...'.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm checking the environment and it's wrong, not in base (root) as what i'm asked for, i fix it by changing it to base kernel